# Code in Python that parses fund holdings pulled from EDGAR, given a ticker or CIK

Tags: python, web-scraping

### Challenge:

Write code in Python that parses fund holdings pulled from EDGAR, given a ticker or CIK.

### Example:

1. For this example, we will use this CIK: 0001166559
2. Start on [this page](http://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html).
3. Enter in the CIK (or ticker), and it will take you [here](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?CIK=0001166559&Find=Search&owner=exclude&action=getcompany).
4. Find the "13F" report documents from the ones listed. Here is a "13F-HR".
5. Parse and generate tab-delimited text from the XML.

### Goals:

The code should be able to use any mutual fund ticker. Try [morningstar.com](http://morningstar.com) or [lipperweb.com](http://lipperweb.com) to find valid tickers.
Be sure to check multiple tickers, since the format of the 13F reports can differ.

### My solution

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

def getHoldings(cik):
    """
    Main function that first finds the most recent 13F form 
    and then passes it to scrapeForm to get the holdings 
    for a particular institutional investor.
    """
    urlSec = "https://www.sec.gov"
    urlForms =  "{}/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK={}&type=13F".format(urlSec, cik)
    urlRecentForm = urlSec + BeautifulSoup(requests.get(urlForms).content,
                                  'lxml').find('a', {"id":"documentsbutton"})['href']
    contents = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(urlRecentForm).content, 'lxml')
    urlTable = "{}{}".format(urlSec,contents.find_all('tr', \
                            {"class" : 'blueRow'})[-1].find('a')['href'])
    return scrapeForm(urlTable)


def scrapeForm(url):
    """
    This function scrapes holdings from particular URL
    """
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'lxml')
    
    holdings = set([h.text for h in soup.find_all((lambda tag : 'issuer' in tag.name.lower()))])
    if(not holdings):
        print("No Holdings at: {}".format(url))
        return
    return holdings
```

Could you provide me some feedback on my code? I completed this challenge recently and just received a general rejection email, so I want to know how could I improve my solution.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few improvements I would apply to the code.

#### Code Style

- address [PEP8 violations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), in particular:

  - *variable and function naming* - your functions and variables follow the camel case convention, but PEP8 and Python community advocate for [`lower_case_with_underscores` naming style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles)
  - watch for the use of [whitespaces around operators and in expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements)
- remove unused imports - `re` module is unused
- the backslash is unnecessary and can be removed
- the parentheses around `not holdings` are redundant and can be removed
- you can create a set using a *set comprehension* directly:

  ```
  holdings = {h.text for h in soup.find_all((lambda tag: 'issuer' in tag.name.lower()))}
  ```
- I would also define `urlSec` url and `urlForms` url template as [proper constants](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants)
- I think you are also overloading the code with too many things in a single expression. Apply the ["Extract Variable" refactoring method](https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractVariable.html) to improve readability and simplify the code
- use [`urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) to join parts of a URL

#### Web-scraping and HTML-parsing

- since you are issuing multiple requests to the same domain, you may re-use [`requests.Session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) instance, which may have a positive impact on performance:

  > if you're making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase
- you may also win performance on HTML parsing by utilizing [`SoupStrainer` class](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) which allows parsing only the specific things in the DOM tree

Improved code:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests


class Scraper:
    BASE_URL = "https://www.sec.gov"
    FORMS_URL_TEMPLATE = "/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK={cik}&type=13F"

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def get_holdings(self, cik):
        """
        Main function that first finds the most recent 13F form
        and then passes it to scrapeForm to get the holdings
        for a particular institutional investor.
        """

        forms_url = urljoin(self.BASE_URL, self.FORMS_URL_TEMPLATE.format(cik=cik))

        # get the recent form address
        parse_only = SoupStrainer('a', {"id": "documentsbutton"})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.session.get(forms_url).content, 'lxml', parse_only=parse_only)
        recent_form_url = soup.find('a', {"id": "documentsbutton"})['href']
        recent_form_url = urljoin(self.BASE_URL, recent_form_url)

        # get the form document URL
        parse_only = SoupStrainer('tr', {"class": 'blueRow'})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.session.get(recent_form_url).content, 'lxml', parse_only=parse_only)
        form_url = soup.find_all('tr', {"class": 'blueRow'})[-1].find('a')['href']
        form_url = urljoin(self.BASE_URL, form_url)

        return self.scrape_document(form_url)

    def scrape_document(self, url):
        """
        This function scrapes holdings from particular document URL
        """
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.session.get(url).content, 'lxml')

        holdings = {h.text for h in soup.find_all((lambda tag: 'issuer' in tag.name.lower()))}
        if not holdings:
            print("No Holdings at: {}".format(url))
            return

        return holdings
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response. I appreciate that.